# Gallio executing Error on Sonar

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, gallio

I have C# project. when I analyzed the project the gallio plugin is not executing. It says that,

```
Gallio won't execute as there are no test projects.
```

But i have test project.  In my pom.xml  file test pattern is

```
<visual.test.project.pattern>*.Tests;*.Test</visual.test.project.pattern>
```

why this happens?
I have Ncover 3 installed in my system. when i analyze the project with mvn sonar:sonar, I had sets properties as

```
-Dsonar.gallio.coverage.tool=NCover
-Dsonar.dotnet.test.assemblies="Assembly files"
```

Comment: Which version of the plugin are you running? The documentation states that the property is "sonar.donet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern" (not "visual.test.project.pattern"). See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/sonar-dotnet-plugin

Comment: I changed it to the new one as `sonar.donet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern` in my Pom.xml file. still the gallio isn't executing.

Comment: Can you add more log and also detail the structure of your solution? It's impossible to help you w/o more information.

Comment: I had solved it Fabrice. Issue in my side. Test pattern i used is not correct. And with the correct pattern it works.